# Find the source file for class / method using ri or fastri for ruby

Tags: ruby

For example I do

```
$fri group_by
---------------------------------------------------- Enumerable#group_by
     enum.group_by {| obj | block }  => a_hash
------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Returns a hash, which keys are evaluated result from the block, 
     and values are arrays of elements in enum corresponding to the key.

        (1..6).group_by {|i| i%3}   #=> {0=>[3, 6], 1=>[1, 4], 2=>[2, 5]}
```

Except I'm pretty sure that group_by is not part of the standard ruby library.
How to find out which library is monkey patching Enumerable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`group_by` is part of the [ruby core](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Enumerable.html#M001150) since 1.8.7.

Answer (score 1):

use the ri_for gem:

```
>> require 'ri_for'
>> Enumerable.ri_for :group_by
sig: Enumerable#group_by arity 0
appears to be a c method
Original code signature: sig: Enumerable#group_by arity 0
#parameters signature: group_by( [] )
Searching ri for
sig: Enumerable#group_by arity 0
...
Nothing known about Enumerable
(end ri)
=> "#"
```

(the fact that it's a c method means it's probably in core)

Comment: currently unable to install ri_for. `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
    Unable to resolve dependencies: ruby2ruby requires sexp_processor (~> 4.0); ParseTree requires sexp_processor (~> 3.2.0); ruby_parser requires sexp_processor (~> 4.1)`